# Scikit-learn fit_transform return type not homogeneous

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm currently using sklearn and something bothers me.
The return type of `Imputer.fit_transform()`, `LabelEncoder.fit_transform`, etc is `numpy.ndarray`, but `OneHotEncoder.fit_transform()` returns a `coo_matrix`.
Is there an explication ?

Thank you.

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imputer works on existing data array. So the output will depend on the input to fit(). If the input is sparse the output is most likely sparse.

LabelEncoder just changes the string values to integer, so it requires a simple array (not sparse) and will output a similar array.

Now coming on to OneHotEncoder, the work of one-hot encoder is to get dummy encoding for a column, in which for a single sample only single 1 is present (thats why called 1-hot) and all others 0.

So if a column of 100 samples has 7 unique categories, then you will get 7 different columns in the output, which will have total 700 cells with only 100 cells having 1 (one for each sample) and remaining 600 cells have data 0. This is about a single column. Now consider this situation for multiple columns on a huge data of samples maybe greater than 10000. In that most cells will be 0. So thats why to save memory, it returns a sparse matrix.

If you have enough memory to handle that you should initialize the OneHotEncoder as:

```
enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
```

In this, the `transform()` will return a simple dense array.